# How do you read lines from a .txt file?

Tags: python, text, io

I have a `.txt` file with 100 50-digit numbers in it. Each number is on a different line.

Example of the file:

```
37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250
46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538
74324986199524741059474233309513058123726617309629
91942213363574161572522430563301811072406154908250
23067588207539346171171980310421047513778063246676
#95 more numbers
```

I want to be able to append each number into a list, after opening the file. How can I do this?

I know how to open the file: `fo = open('file_name', 'r')`. And how to close it at the end: `fo.close()`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is *basic* file I/O and the answer can be found in the Python documentation and tutorials.

Comment: Let me guess: [Project Euler #13](http://projecteuler.net/problem=13)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the simplest way I can think of:

```
with open('numbers.txt') as file:
    lst = [line.strip() for line in file]
```

Comment: Thanks. If you actually want a list of integers rather than strings, use `[int(line) for line in file]` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate through the lines in a file really easily:

```
for line in fo:
    # Do whatever with the line
```

Answer (score 3):

Chapter 7 of the Python Tutorial can answer this: http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files